# Accessing Correct Database to Create REST API Endpoint

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, wp-query, rest-api

So I have multiple databases associated with the database where my wordpress website is hosted. I was wondering if I can access all of said databases with $wpdb or will I need to initiate a connection using mySQL credentials for said database. Here is my code, it is returning a 500 error so I know the issue is on the server side. On the server I have various databases with the same prefix followed by _"suffix". Below I am trying to access the database pre_schools which is a separate database from where I find all the essential wp stuff ie. wp posts, users, etc. I tried initiating a new WP connection as well and no dice either. If anyone has any idea the direction to push me in it would be much appreciated.

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name:  College ID API
* Requires PHP: 7.2
*/

function collegeid(WP_REST_Request $request)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $schools=$wpdb::select("pre_schools");
    $data = $schools->get_results("SELECT Colleges ' . $wpdb->prefix . '");
    return $data;

};



add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v1', '/schools', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => ['collegeid'],
        'permission_callback'=>'__return_true' 
    ) );
} );





?>
```

Comment: 1. Are you _sure_ you need to directly access the database? In most cases you can accomplish what you need with WP functions.  2. If you _do_ need to access the DB, you'll need to read up on [the `wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) and its methods. For example, [`select()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/select/) is not a static method, and your [`get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) will be something like `SELECT Colleges wp_`, which... won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can access another database using the `wpdb` class and its associated methods. You will need to instantiate a new connection to the other database using the appropriate credentials. Here is the basic code to set up the new connection and query the database:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("<your SQL query here>");
```

Replace the parameters to the `wpdb()` method as required and construct the necessary query for `get_results()`.